# glOrtho doesent work it still gets mapped to default coordinates

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl, opengl-compat

so im using pyopengl in python to use opengl but when i use glOrtho in my reshape function to map my coordinates it doesn't work it still gets mapped to -1 - 1 here is my code:

```
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from OpenGL.GL import *

width, height = 500,500

def rectangle(x, y, width, height, color, fill):
    if fill:
        glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
        glColor3ub(color[0], color[1], color[2])
        glVertex2f(x - width/2, y + height/2)
        glVertex2f(x + width/2, y + height/2)
        glVertex2f(x + width/2, y - height/2)
        glVertex2f(x - width/2, y - height/2)
        glColor3ub(255, 255, 255)
        glEnd()
    else:
        glBegin(GL_LINES)
        glColor3ub(color[0], color[1], color[2])
        glVertex2f(x - width/2, y + height/2)
        glVertex2f(x + width/2, y + height/2)
        glVertex2f(x + width/2, y - height/2)
        glVertex2f(x - width/2, y - height/2)
        glColor3ub(255, 255, 255)
        glEnd()

def draw():
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    glClearColor(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 1)
    glLoadIdentity()

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2f(1, 1)
    glVertex2f(-1, 1)
    glVertex2f(-1, -1)
    glVertex2f(100, -1)
    glEnd()

    glutSwapBuffers()


def reshape(w, h):
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()
    glOrtho(0, w, 0, h, 0, 1000)


glutInit()
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA) # Set the display mode to be colored
glutInitWindowSize(width, height)   # Set the w and h of your window
glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0)   # Set the position at which this windows should appear
window = glutCreateWindow("OpenGL") # Set a window title
glutReshapeFunc(reshape)
glutDisplayFunc(draw) # defines display func
glutIdleFunc(draw) # Keeps the window open
glutMainLoop()  # Keeps the above created window displaying/running in a loop
```

help me solve this problem i dont see a reason why it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glOrtho` doesn't work because in the `glLoadIdentity()` instruction in the `draw` function. `glLoadIdentity()` loads the [Identity matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix). Change the matrix mode after `glOrtho` with [`glMatrixMode`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glMatrixMode.xml). This ensures that the projection matrix is preserved, but the identity matrix is loaded into the model view matrix. OpenGL is a state engine. Once a state has been changed, it is retained until it is changed again, even beyond frames.

```py
def reshape(w, h):
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()
    glOrtho(0, w, 0, h, 0, 1000)
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
```